# Whats is taco memory and why am I low on it?

Tags: android

04-23 23:06:09.458: ERROR/taco(1350): LowMemory.

I constantly see this in logcat, but what does it mean?

Comment: taco memory: closely related to burrito stack ;)

Comment: Unless 'taco' is an application you're developing yourself then this isn't a programming related question and doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: what has that pid? Any other hint above in the logcat?

Answer (score 2):

This is what the log line you posted means:

- The `04-23 23:06:09.458` is a timestamp for April 23rd, 11:06 PM.
- The log statement is of Log level `ERROR`.
- `taco` is an application-specific tag that is being passed into the Logger.
- The `(1350)` is the originating process Id.
- `LowMemory` is the message the application (the afformentioned `taco`) has requested be logged.

There's more information about what's contained in Logcat messages (and how to filter them) on the the [Android Developer Site about ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat).

If you're curious about that specific log statement, the first step is figuring out what application is logging using the `taco` log tag and why (or at least when) it's logging this message.

Comment: I know what the logcat message is. And I have 2 separate phones (CBW Blaze on 2.1 and Moto Droid2 on 2.2) I'm testing on that have the message, which leads me to believe its something OS related. But I still don't know what.

Comment: Is there any 3rd party app on both of these phones that could be generating this message? I just checked the logs on a Moto Droid on 2.2 and a Samsung Fascinate on 2.1 and I didn't find any messages logged under this tag. Do you notice if this occurs all the time, or only during certain circumstances?

Comment: On my device, the pid that produced taco is showing as com.android.settings. I used top from adb shell to query this.